# Autofac - Singleton interface resolved as transient

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm building a WPF application and using Autofac as an IoC container. The scenario is kind of hard to describe but I'll try to give the relevant piece of code below:

My app bootstrapper contains the following code to register the viewmodels in my app:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblySource)
       .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
       .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.Namespace) && type.Namespace.Contains("ViewModels"))
       .AssignableTo<INotifyPropertyChanged>()
       .AsSelf()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

(note the `InstancePerDependency()` call, which I have to make, because I display many instances of a view)

Then I have the following code to register implementers of an open generic:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblySource)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(INotificationHandler<>))
       .AsSelf()
       .SingleInstance();
```

To avoid passing the container into my event dispatcher, I'm passing it instead a delegate as follows:

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx => { return t => Container.Resolve(t ); });
```

And the last bit of code is causing me a problem: It's causing the ViewModels that implement the `INotificationHandler` interface to have instances created on every call, while I need only once instance to be resolved, and the ViewModels implement this generic interface will have only one instance created throughout the application.

**Question is**: How can I make Autofac resolve single instances of the ViewModels that Implement the `INotificationHandler<T>` interface, while keeping the other ViewModels to be created `PerDependency` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude ViewModels that implements **INotificationHandler<>** in your first registration. So change your first registration to:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.Namespace) && type.Namespace.Contains("ViewModels"))
            .Where(type => !type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(INotificationHandler<>)))
            .AssignableTo<INotifyPropertyChanged>()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem still occurs even with your code. Where should I investigate further ?

Comment: Can you show how your registrations looks, after the container has been built?

Comment: Thanks, again. I fixed my registrations and now it works as it should.